# How to get the value of react component - AceEditor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor

I am facing the following issue while using `AceEditor` react component https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace

I am using `AceEditor` as user input, after user enters code, he(she) presses the `Run` button. (see the picture) How do I extract the text that users enters from `AceEditor` component ? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the `onChange` event (explained in the docs) and store the value passed into the callback somewhere, perhaps in the [component's state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) if the `Run` button is on the same page. Then, when user clicks the button just retrieve it via `this.state.xxx`

Answer (score 4):

It's not necessary to use onChange.

```
<AceEditor ref="aceEditor" />

this.refs.aceEditor.editor.getValue()
```

Answer (score 2):

With the latest React v16.12+ `this.refName.current.editor.getValue()` works to get string value which can be parsed using `JSON.parse`.

Ref should be instantiated as:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.refName = React.createRef();
  }
```

and passed to AceEditor component:

```
     <AceEditor
        ref={this.refName}
     />
```

Answer (score 1):

AceEditor provides an **`onChange` event which you can use to retrieve the current content of the editor** whenever the user changes it and then store the value in your own data store or your component's state.

This way, you are able to retrieve the value whenever you need it.

[More about the editor's properties](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace#available-props).

The readme also provides [an example](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace#usage), demostrating its usage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind this state to the onchange function in constructor of class.It worked for me.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {code:"code"};
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

onChange(newValue) {
    this.state.code = newValue;
    alert(this.state.code);
}
```

Ace Editor's Onchange is

```
onChange = {
   this.onChange
}
```